# Semantics: Unit/second versus unit-second

Tags: units, notation, unit-conversion

I've been trying to make sense of an unusual bit of mathematical and notational semantics in my electrical engineering studies:

Velocity is typically given in units of metres per second ( $ v = \frac{m}{s} = m \cdot s^{-1} $ ). That is, a velocity of one metre per second is defined as a rate of positional change of one metre in a time period of one second.

*However,* some examples where this notation isn't the case in electrical engineering include the following:

- Charge: $ C = A \cdot s $, Ampere-seconds, One ampere of current passing through a conductor during a time period of one second is equivalent to one coulomb of charge transferred.
- Energy: $ J = W \cdot s $, Watt-seconds, One watt of power produced or consumed during a time period of one second is equivalent to one joule of energy produced or consumed.
- Magnetic flux: $ Wb = V \cdot s $, Volt-seconds, A change of electromagnetic potential of one volt over a time period of one second generates a magnetic flux of one weber.
- Inductance: $ H = \Omega \cdot s $, Ohm-seconds, A change of electrical resistance of one ohm over a time period of one second is equivalent to an inductance of one henry (I think; I may be interpreting this one incorrectly).

These are just a few examples where electrical engineering is chock full of "A rate of something happening in a time period of one second" is basically defined as that something *multiplied* by time, as opposed to divided by time as in the case of velocity.

As far as I can tell the phrasing is effectively equivalent, but mathematically, the difference is profound, and very, *very* confusing. Can someone explain the difference between the two?

Comment: 1 watt = 1 joule per second. Etc.

Comment: The phrasing is not "effectively equivalent" even if it *looks* similar. The difference is between multiplying and dividing - if you really find that "very *very* confusing," perhaps you need to review some basic algebra before you go any further.

Comment: I don't get what you mean.  $A/B=C$ is equivalent to $A=B\times C$ so what's the fuss?

Comment: @ZeroTheHero I wasn't making the connection of reframing the velocity definition as displacement is equal to velocity multiplied by time, and vice-versa for the other definitions, as Ziggurat and Philip Wood both helpfully pointed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Velocity, $m/s$, is a measure of the rate at which something moves. I guess you could define displacement as velocity-seconds, a measure of how far something moves at a given rate over a second. In your examples, it is not rates being defined, but the effect of going at a certain rate over a period of time. Amps are Coulombs per second, so you can define Coulombs as the amount of charge moved over a second at a rate of one amp. If you multiply the rate at which something happens by how long that something happens, you will get how much of that something happened.

Comment: Okay that actually makes sense! Didn't occur to me to change the frame of reference for the velocity definition to match the definitions of the electrical units. Thanks! :)

Comment: A useful example is a knot-second as a unit of length...

Answer (score -1):

The four cases you've quoted are all correct. Physicists, though, would use plain text and not italics, for the units, and would omit the dot standing for multiplication. Other than that, all four can be cast in the form of quotients, or, if you prefer, rates. Thus…

$$\text{A}=\text{C}\ \text{s}^{-1},\  \text{W}=\text{J}\ \text{s}^{-1}, \ \text{V}=\text{Wb}\ \text{s}^{-1}, \  \Omega=\text{H}\ \text{s}^{-1}$$

Comment: Ziggurat's answer is slightly better phrased, but yours is no less equally apt to answer my question. Thanks a lot! Really helped to understand what's going on.